# Combine and fuse the results of two SQL queries with UNION

Tags: sql, union

I am writing two seperate SQL queries to get data for two different dates like so:

```
SELECT number, sum(sales) as sales, sum(discount) sa discount, sum(margin) as margin
FROM table_a
WHERE day = '2019-08-09'
GROUP BY number

SELECT number, sum(sales) as sales, sum(discount) sa discount, sum(margin) as margin
FROM table_a
WHERE day = '2018-08-10'
GROUP BY number
```

I tried fusing them like so to get the results for the same number in one row from two different dates:

```
SELECT number, sum(sales) as sales, sum(discount) sa discount, sum(margin) as margin, 0 as sales_n1, 0 as discount_n1, 0 as margin_n1
FROM table_a
WHERE day = '2019-08-09'
GROUP BY number
UNION
SELECT number, 0 as sales, 0 as discount, 0 as margin, sum(sales_n1) as sales_n1, sum(discount_n1) as discount_n1, sum(margin_n1) as margin_n1
FROM table_a
WHERE day = '2018-08-10'
GROUP BY number
```

But it didn't work as I get the rows for the first query with zeroes for the columns defined as zero followed by the columns of the second query in the same fashion.

How can I correct this to have the desired output ?

Comment: Why are the columns `sales, discount, margin` non aggregated? You should use `MIN()`, `MAX()`, etc. on them since they are not mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: It can only be MySQL 5.7.4 or older. I haven't seen that [wrong] syntax anywhere else.

Comment: I corrected the details of my question along with the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT number,
       sum(case when day = '2019-08-09' then sales end) as sales_20190809,
       sum(case when day = '2019-08-09' then discount end) sa discount, sum(margin) as margin_20190810,
       sum(case when day = '2019-08-10' then sales end) as sales_20190809,
       sum(case when day = '2019-08-10' then discount end) sa discount, sum(margin) as margin_20190810
FROM table_a
WHERE day IN ('2019-08-09', '2019-08-10')
GROUP BY number;
```

If you want the numbers in *different* rows (which you don't seem to), then use aggregation:

```
SELECT day, number, sum(sales) as sales, sum(discount) as discount, sum(margin) as margin
FROM table_a
WHERE day IN ('2019-08-09', '2019-08-10')
GROUP BY day, number
```